# Angular reactive form without validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to have reactive form without validation?
I did not have any `Validators` in FormBuilder, but it still add `ng-valid` class to input on change, but I do not need it.

Comment: This is not configurable hardcoded. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts#L29

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to import reactive forms and it workz.

Comment: You are probably did not understand my question. Everything is work, I just don't need to have validation classes on inputs.